# Javascript - Full string doesn't show in google chrome console, only show till first comma

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
//$('body').html($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));
console.log($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-images="http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/9c34260e-96e3-4d67-9bbb-e7ccce1a6f0c-1220449977.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/7133f252-4396-40c6-9860-ccb27aee4bc7-1220449982.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/9ce7a32b-e031-4670-8689-1fe02b356d59-1220449986.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/02cf0c6c-3fb1-4c61-bd32-b74b04e95c99-1220449993.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/38878ca9-80ed-4d05-900b-82b6ac834f47-1220449995.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/e17a2405-4678-4b95-8f52-ad1d4a435368-1220449998.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80,http://pictures.immobilienscout24.de/listings/6705b14f-e757-4637-9191-7edc6df4eb79-1220450000.jpg/ORIG/resize/1106x830%3E/format/jpg/quality/80">
```

If you have Google Chrome browser, you will see only part of the string (till first comma), not the full string

[image]

Another question is when i add 
`$('body').html($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));` before the `console.log($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));` it returns `undefined`, I am not sure why?

Could someone help pls?

Comment: What do you mean by one string is showing there?

Comment: To me it looks like Chrome is just shortening the log for aesthetics. When I run your code and view the console, it displays like yours, but if I click on the log itself it opens the full string in a new page.

Comment: @void hi, i have amended the question, i meant it is showing only the part of the string

Comment: @nik I see the complete string comma separated. Even in the image you have attached.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, it is unexpected behaviour from Google Chrome, atleast it should show dots(..) in the end of the string, i was working on a project, and trying to figure out what was wrong in my code, it took be 1 hour  to notice that it is actually bug in chrome, anyway, Thanks:)

Comment: It is by design. Not a bug. However, you need to revise your design because the `data-` attribute should not have that large string. It is ugly and not maintainable. You already experienced it: you had troubles with debugging it.

Comment: @KarelG, Hi, Thanks for your advice, but I have many images and I have to bind many images to each image, so that when a user clicks on them a slider(modal)(which shows all the relevant images) appears, and there are many other things that I can't mention here,  I think it is the best choice for what i wanna achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question: Chrome is simply shortening the string in the console for displaying purposes. You are still logging the complete string.

To your second question: When you do

```
$('body').html($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));
console.log($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));
```

the first line removes all inner html of the `<body>` tag, and writes the raw `data-images` string to it. In the second line, you try to select all img tags (which have been removed by the `$('body').html()`). This results in `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

with:

> $('body').html($('img').eq(0).attr("data-images"));

you are changing the html content of the body element. So if you execute that before your console.log statement there will be no  element any more. You will see the details if you execute the statement and then inspect the html page.